# What is causing an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." in my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, runtime-error

My app is throwing an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` in the following files:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . Tweet.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . Timeline.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . TimelineView.js:2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . app.js:2
```

However, when I refer to the files, to checkout the lines in question, I see no errors:

Tweet.js:

```
var com = com || {}
, com.apress = com.apress || {}
, com.apress.model = com.apress.model || {}
, com.apress.model.Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

Timeline.js:

```
var com = com || {}
, com.apress = com.apress || {}
, com.apress.collection = com.apress.collection || {}

[...]
```

TimelineView.js:

```
var com = com || {}
, com.apress = com.apress || {}
, com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {}

[...]
```

app.js:

```
var com = com || {}
, com.apress = com.apress || {}
, com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {}
, com.apress.view.TimelineView = Backbone.View.extend({
});

$(function() {
    var timelineView = new com.apress.view.TimelineView();
});
```

I consistently get these errors and resolve them without ever understanding how I resolved them. **What causes** `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` errors and how do I resolve the ones above?

Comment: Dear anonymous down-voters: If you feel the need to down-vote, at least have the common courtesy to leave feedback or a reason for your down-vote so I can improve the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is not a valid character in a variable name, so you can't do

```
var com.apress = ... ;
```

Instead of using a variable declaration statement with multiple declarations, you should have a single declaration and simple assignments:

```
var com = com || {};
com.apress = com.apress || {};
com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {};
```

Answer (score -1):

try encapsulating with brackets

```
var com = (com || {})
, com.apress = (com.apress || {}) , ....
```